# Recently upgraded to CiviCRM 5.35.1. (Wordpress 5.7.1) Send Mail is no longer available in Action dropdown

Tags: sendmail

When I attempt to send an email to a small group of individuals using Send Mail. I can not find that option in any of the usual action drown offerings after searching contacts or members. I looked in the various admin areas to see if I had to turn that feature on but could not find a switch.

Comment: The action is called "email - send now" - is that what you mean?

Comment: Are you testing and have set a staging or development environment? That would disable the mail facility.

Comment: I was able to resolve the missing mail problem.  In the Settings - Outbound Mail page under General Allow mail from logged in contact was set to NO.  I flipped it to YES and the usual mail options in Actions drop down now appear.